# How to avoid segmentation fault in a buffer overflow exploit

Tags: exploit, buffer-overflow, c

I have an excersise of making a buffer flow exploit for directing a function insinde another function without calling it. First I need to print "now inside entrance()" then print "now inside secret()"

I was able to print "now inside secret()" by overflowing the buffer via assingning above address of doNotTouch which is return address of entrance function. But now I am getting a segmentation fault, which I shouldn't have.

I am doing this exercise on a x86_64 Debian system and gcc verison 4.9. I am prohibited to call any function or editing outside the given area in entrance(). I also shouldn't compile with compile options.

Thanks in advance

```
 #include <stdio.h>

void secret()
{
    printf("now inside secret()!\n");
}

void entrance()
{
int doNotTouch[4];
// can only modify this section BEGIN
// cant call secret(), maybe use secret (pointer to function)

*(doNotTouch + 6) = &secret;

// can only modify this section END
printf("now inside entrance()!\n");

}

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    entrance();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you had it working before, what did you change that made it break? What do you mean about compile options?

Comment: So you've modified the stack so that `entrance()`, instead of returning to main, jumps to secret instead. But now what happens when secret returns? Where will it return to?